# How to run "single test case" in XCTest?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

When I click "Run MyTest3" in XCode's Test Navigator, it also runs "MyTest1" and "MyTest2".
Is there a way to run single test case at a time, just like GHUnitTest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is an option to do that.

Step 1:

[image: Test Case Tab]

Step 2:

[image: Run]

Step 3:

[image: Status]

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I thought "MyTest1" and "MyTest2" were executed before "MyTest3", but they are not. XCTest just outputs `'[MyTest1 testExample]' started` without actually executing it.